# Implementing chat in my JSF page

Tags: jsf, chat

I have J2EE web application which uses JSF framework. Now I am trying to add chat functionality to my application. The problem that I am facing is

When someone pings me, i should be able to see a chat notification on my jsp page. Which means server should be able to update my page when new chat notification comes. Please tell me how can my jsp page listen to incoming packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into push technologies. Many JSF libraries support it directly: [icefaces](http://www.icefaces.org/main/ajax-java/ajaxpush.iface), [richfaces](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_push.html) and [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chat.jsf) at least. If you don't want to use any of these you may also check out [atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere), but this will require some javascript and server side coding.